# Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I have simple payment page which I am going to show in popup using partial view. In `.cshtml` page, I have following javascript code below html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function () {
        Stripe.setPublishableKey(publishablekey);
    });
</script>
```

When I run the project that popup shows successfully but in the console, there is an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added Stripe reference line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>` in that page on which I am going to show partial view in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the browser cannot load the Stripe js library. That could happen because your user has lost their internet connection, or maybe (but less likely) the website that is serving the Stripe library is temporarily unavailable. To handle this case gracefully you could check to see whether Stripe is undefined.

For example:

```
if (typeof Stripe === "undefined") {
    alert("Unexpected Error");
}
```

Or check for the opposite before using it

```
if (typeof Stripe !== "undefined") {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(publishablekey);
}
```

Comment: On the separate page, it is working fine but when I try to render that page in popup using the partial view that error throws.